# Python - test that succeeds when exception is not raised

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception

I know about `unittest` Python module.

I know about `assertRaises()` method of `TestCase` class.

I would like to write a test that succeeds when an exception is **not** raised.

Any hints please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python unittest - opposite of assertRaises?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319825/python-unittest-opposite-of-assertraises)

Comment: @brandizzi - check the date on that "duplicate" question ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The test runner will catch all exceptions you didn't assert would be raised.
Thus:

```
doStuff()
self.assert_(True)
```

This should work fine. You can leave out the self.assert_ call, since it doesn't really do anything. I like to put it there to document that I didn't forget an assertion.

Comment: This way the test will not fail but raise an error. The try/except approach mentioned in the other answer is a better answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 25):

```
def runTest(self):
    try:
        doStuff()
    except:
        self.fail("Encountered an unexpected exception.")
```

UPDATE: As liw.fi mentions, the default result is a success, so the example above is something of an antipattern. You should probably only use it if you want to do something special before failing. You should also catch the most specific exceptions possible.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but Python uses try...except, not try...catch

Comment: Thanks - the 'answer before coffee' gotcha strikes again.

Comment: This has the downside of losing the original stack trace making the test harder to debug on failure.

Answer (score 6):

I use this pattern for the kind of assertion you've asked:

```
with self.assertRaises(Exception):
    try:
        doStuff()
    except:
        pass
    else:
        raise Exception
```

It will fail exactly when exception is raised by doStuff().

Comment: Kosii-Is this a correct solution too ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4319870/6648326

Comment: I don't understand this syntax. What is it doing?