# Python unittest - opposite of assertRaises?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to write a test to establish that an Exception is not raised in a given circumstance.

It's straightforward to test if an Exception **is** raised ...

```
sInvalidPath=AlwaysSuppliesAnInvalidPath()
self.assertRaises(PathIsNotAValidOne, MyObject, sInvalidPath)
```

... but how can you do the **opposite**.

Something like this i what I'm after ...

```
sValidPath=AlwaysSuppliesAValidPath()
self.assertNotRaises(PathIsNotAValidOne, MyObject, sValidPath)
```

Comment: You could always simply do whatever ought to work in the test. If it raises an error, that will show up (counted as an error, rather than a failure). Of course, that assumes that it doesn't raise any error, rather than just a defined type of error. Other than that, I guess you'd have to write your own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - test that succeeds when exception is not raised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647900/python-test-that-succeeds-when-exception-is-not-raised)

Comment: It turns out that you can in fact implement an `assertNotRaises` method that shares 90% of its code/behavior with `assertRaises` in about ~30-ish lines of code. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49062929/425458) for details.

Comment: I want this so I can compare two functions with `hypothesis` to make sure they produce the same output for all kinds of input, while ignoring the cases where the original raises an exception.  `assume(func(a))` doesn't work because output can be an array with ambiguous truth value.  So I just want to call a function and get `True` if it doesn't fail.  `assume(func(a) is not None)` works I guess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a Python unittest if an exception isn't raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181555/pass-a-python-unittest-if-an-exception-isnt-raised)

Answer (score 566, accepted):

```
def run_test(self):
    try:
        myFunc()
    except ExceptionType:
        self.fail("myFunc() raised ExceptionType unexpectedly!")
```

Comment: @hiwaylon - No, this is the correct solution in fact. The solution proposed by user9876 is conceptually flawed: if you test for the non-raising of say `ValueError`, but `ValueError` is instead raised, your test must exit with a failure condition, not an error one. On the other hand, if in running the same code you would raise a `KeyError`, that would be an error, not a failure. In python - differently than some other languages - Exceptions are routinely used for control flow, this is why we have the `except <ExceptionName>` syntax indeed. To that regard, user9876's solution is simply wrong.

Comment: @mac - Is this also a correct solution ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4711722/6648326

Comment: This one has the unfortunate effect of showing < 100% coverage (the except will never happen) for tests.

Comment: @Shay, IMO you should always exclude the test files themselves from the coverage reports (as they almost always run 100% by definition, you would be artificially inflating the reports)

Comment: @original-bbq-sauce, wouldn't that leave me open to unintentionally skipped tests. E.g., typo in test name (ttst_function), wrong run configuration in pycharm, etc.?

Comment: @Shay it would yeah. Typos will be very easy to miss. But if you have the wrong configuration, it will clearly show when you run the tests: the number or runs won't match what you were expecting.

Comment: requiring 100% coverage on test files catches has caught more than a few mistakes for me that otherwise would likely not have been found.

Comment: it's very weird, that unittest doesn't have this implemented

Answer (score 88):

> Hi - I want to write a test to establish that an Exception is not raised in a given circumstance.

That's the default assumption -- exceptions are not raised.

If you say nothing else, that's assumed in every single test.

You don't have to actually write an any assertion for that.

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta Well the accepted answer makes the test more pythonic than this one. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: No other commenter has pointed out *why* this answer is wrong, though it's the same reason that user9876's answer is wrong: failures and errors are different things in test code. If your function *were* to throw an exception during a test that doesn't assert, the test framework would treat that as an **error**, rather than a failure to not assert.

Comment: @CoreDumpError I understand the difference between a failure and an error, but wouldn't this force you to surround **every test** with a try/exception construction? Or would you recommend to do that only for tests that explicitly raise an exception under some condition (which basically means that the exception is *expected*).

Comment: @federicojasson You answered your own question quite well in that second sentence. Errors vs failures in tests can be succinctly described as "unexpected crashes" vs "unintended behavior", respectively. You want your tests to show an error when your function crashes, but not when an exception that you know it will throw given certain inputs gets thrown when given different inputs.

Answer (score 58):

Just call the function.  If it raises an exception, the unit test framework will flag this as an error.  You might like to add a comment, e.g.:

```
sValidPath=AlwaysSuppliesAValidPath()
# Check PathIsNotAValidOne not thrown
MyObject(sValidPath)
```

Edited to add clarifications from the comments:

- Unit tests can have 3 results: Pass, Fail, Error.  (Actually more if you count XPass/XFail/Skip...)
- If you're testing a particular exception is not thrown, and it is thrown, then in theory that should be a Fail.  But the code above makes it an Error, which is theoretically "wrong".
- As a practical matter, with an Error your test runner will probably print the stack trace, which may be useful debugging the failure.  With a Fail you probably won't see the stack trace.
- As a practical matter, with a Fail you can mark the test as "Expected to Fail".  With an Error you probably can't do that, although you can mark the test as "skip".
- As a practical matter, making the test case report an Error requires additional code.
- Whether the difference between "Error" and "Failure" matters depends on your processes.  The way my team uses unit tests, they have to all pass. (Agile programming, with a continuous integration machine that runs all the unit tests). What actually matters to my team is "do all the unit tests pass?" (i.e. "is Jenkins green?"). So for my team, there's no practical difference between "Fail" and "Error".
- Due to the advantages mentioned above (less code, seeing the stack trace), and the fact that Fail/Error are treated the same by my team, I use this approach.
- You may have different requirements if you use your unit tests in a different way, especially if your processes treat "fail" and "error" differently, or if you want to be able to mark tests as "expected failure".
- If you would rather have this test report an Error, use DGH's answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. As you say it works perfectly well and I hadn't thought of it before you mentioned it. I ended up preferring the approach of DGH however but thanks anyway.

Comment: Failures and Errors are conceptually different. Furthermore, since in python Exceptions are routinely used for control flow, this will make very very difficult to understand at a glance (=without exploring the test code) if you have broken your logic or your code...

Comment: Either your test passes or it doesn't.  If it doesn't pass, you're going to have to go fix it.  Whether it's reported as a "failure" or an "error" is mostly irrelevant.  There is one difference: with my answer you'll see the stack trace so you can see where PathIsNotAValidOne was thrown; with the accepted answer you won't have that information so debugging will be harder.  (Assuming Py2; not sure if Py3 is better at this).

Comment: @user9876 - Nope.  The test exit conditions are 3 (pass/nopass/error), not 2 as you seem to erroneously believe.  The difference between errors and failures is substantial and treating them as if they were the same is just poor programming.  If you don't believe me, just look around to how test runners work and what decision trees they implement fro failures and errors.  A good starting point for python is [the `xfail` decorator](http://pytest.org/latest/skipping.html) in pytest.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you use unit tests.  The way my team uses unit tests, they have to all pass.  (Agile programming, with a continuous integration machine that runs all the unit tests).  I know that the test case can report "pass", "fail" or "error".  But at a high level what actually matters to my team is "do all the unit tests pass?" (i.e. "is Jenkins green?").  So for my team, there's no practical difference between "fail" and "error".  You may have different requirements if you use your unit tests in a different way.

Comment: @mac Thanks for clarifying these points, and while I agree with you, it is true that when using DGH's approach I cannot see the stack trace. How do I get it to print it in the correct way?

Comment: @user9876 the difference between 'fail' and 'error' is the difference between "my assert failed" and "my test doesn't even get to the assert".  That, to me, is a useful distinction during fixing tests, but I guess, as you say, not for everyone.

Comment: @Michael if you need to see the stack trace, you are missing the point of the question.  It's like asking to see a stack trace for a test where you assert an exception **is** raised.  You just need to see your test code raises the exception; you don't actually want to see the trace.  Here you want to assert the exception is **not** raised.

Comment: In the case where an expected exception is thrown, then the test has passed, so there is no need to debug, so you don't care about the stack trace.  In the case where an unexpected exception is thrown, then the test has not passed, and you have to debug why the test has not passed, so seeing the stack trace can be useful.

Answer (score 21):

You can define `assertNotRaises` by reusing about 90% of the original implementation of `assertRaises` in the `unittest` module. With this approach, you end up with an `assertNotRaises` method that, aside from its reversed failure condition, behaves identically to `assertRaises`.

### TLDR and live demo

It turns out to be surprisingly easy to add an `assertNotRaises` method to `unittest.TestCase` (it took me about 4 times as long to write this answer as it did the code). Here's [a live demo of the `assertNotRaises` method in action](https://tio.run/##vVVNb9swDD3Pv4LIDnEKz0jXQ7cCAVYUG9BDe9h6GwZBcehGqy0ZktzGLfrbO9JfieN2RXeYLrZl8vHxiaSKyq@NPnp6UnlhrAdd5kUF0oEugnar1Mp7dD5Ircn7rziRDqE1EafOofXfpXLozoz2uPGdu7cywaVMboIgyaRznfGlGdqHz4HMTgKgNZlMJCTNFuRSy2u0UDpcgTfMIcMcNYVaIzQgaGM5jAI5UqaruMY712u0yjsYpxQ/RwOkXoHSt7TvgP1iIXCjvBBhHMezFrujWj9XmEJv5DBLI8BNInxVYPN2K7OSXv2yzZGXSnsjUHQGxsOl0bg14PUenDcW2RILr4yO4E5R/HJH6whSYyGTJARY9FYhhRugMKW4h4DFllPMaKKHCpnBLBg4e1sNOfFiAC1zJKwWvMDE44q04m0hgj1rCg2nnsgtS49frTX276DehgPg2cCatKv/muXv2mOMVf8Wlg/2m1RZaTGcPDxCvbGCZQUPj5OYdMulD7u40QilR@oCzYY8MHNvjT2KugM5hutPJk4ylFakljxcSIW0PSQ689JquLIldm13UV1RjZ9RiYd9wXc7bQlyze61TV@6jeRip@gOpL129Di4ueO3nTLuOnXxYq8/h8eRtnmPSqxNqcWO19SSGYbTPb7TCBpaLakeIlVaZlm130rLwnz4ePTp8/yE50rJJrC0KG9AUsQULeoEIalI6oHnNkVuj8GvVu8f6JXHvBd9q/@O2nwKwjWWQndJXNTjpJZ@R1WaLIxAc0/p6/1z4pEtd@fQ7iziJa0lsrqI79EaFx7O540277YK0cRQGxpzbGVJXpPXD6V9OI/IIXLqHhfseTIeJft1c65XuKmbmk/E0hDo0hQRhYng8HjYN69o0lXO20XZuzfepE5PjBfPxdeS3ZPmnzV9R4x@qs0vYnV4HPQ0vvSt23VQO01eUY@tXpLOr6UfKZeSQ6NfUVhTWEVXyX9VjvPnumF9WhUCxVdqc5csFlMhcqm0ENPGsVeGd8NZ8PT0Bw). Just [like `assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises), you can either pass a callable and args to `assertNotRaises`, or you can use it in a `with` statement. The live demo includes a test cases that demonstrates that `assertNotRaises` works as intended.

#### Details

The implementation of `assertRaises` in `unittest` is fairly complicated, but with a little bit of clever subclassing you can override and reverse its failure condition.

`assertRaises` is a short method that basically just creates an instance of the `unittest.case._AssertRaisesContext` class and returns it (see its definition in the `unittest.case` module). You can define your own `_AssertNotRaisesContext` class by subclassing `_AssertRaisesContext` and overriding its `__exit__` method:

```
import traceback
from unittest.case import _AssertRaisesContext

class _AssertNotRaisesContext(_AssertRaisesContext):
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        if exc_type is not None:
            self.exception = exc_value.with_traceback(None)

            try:
                exc_name = self.expected.__name__
            except AttributeError:
                exc_name = str(self.expected)

            if self.obj_name:
                self._raiseFailure("{} raised by {}".format(exc_name,
                    self.obj_name))
            else:
                self._raiseFailure("{} raised".format(exc_name))

        else:
            traceback.clear_frames(tb)

        return True
```

Normally you define test case classes by having them inherit from `TestCase`. If you instead inherit from a subclass `MyTestCase`:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertNotRaises(self, expected_exception, *args, **kwargs):
        context = _AssertNotRaisesContext(expected_exception, self)
        try:
            return context.handle('assertNotRaises', args, kwargs)
        finally:
            context = None
```

all of your test cases will now have the `assertNotRaises` method available to them.

Comment: IMNSHO this should be added to the unittest library..

Answer (score 18):

I am the original poster and I accepted the above answer by DGH without having first used it in the code.

Once I did use I realised that it needed a little tweaking to actually do what I needed it to do (to be fair to DGH he/she did say "or something similar" !).

I thought it was worth posting the tweak here for the benefit of others:

```
    try:
        a = Application("abcdef", "")
    except pySourceAidExceptions.PathIsNotAValidOne:
        pass
    except:
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

What I was attempting to do here was to ensure that if an attempt was made to instantiate an Application object with a second argument of spaces the pySourceAidExceptions.PathIsNotAValidOne would be raised.

I believe that using the above code (based heavily on DGH's answer) will do that.

Comment: Since you are clarifying your question and not answering it you should have edited it (not answered it).Please see my answer below.

Comment: It seems to be quite the opposite to the original problem. `self.assertRaises(PathIsNotAValidOne, MyObject, sInvalidPath)` should do the job in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I've found it useful to monkey-patch `unittest` as follows:

```
def assertMayRaise(self, exception, expr):
  if exception is None:
    try:
      expr()
    except:
      info = sys.exc_info()
      self.fail('%s raised' % repr(info[0]))
  else:
    self.assertRaises(exception, expr)

unittest.TestCase.assertMayRaise = assertMayRaise
```

This clarifies intent when testing for the absence of an exception:

```
self.assertMayRaise(None, does_not_raise)
```

This also simplifies testing in a loop, which I often find myself doing:

```
# ValueError is raised only for op(x,x), op(y,y) and op(z,z).
for i,(a,b) in enumerate(itertools.product([x,y,z], [x,y,z])):
  self.assertMayRaise(None if i%4 else ValueError, lambda: op(a, b))
```

Comment: What is a monkey-patch?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch.  After adding ``assertMayRaise`` to ``unittest.TestSuite`` you can just pretend it's part of the ``unittest`` library.

Answer (score 3):

```
def _assertNotRaises(self, exception, obj, attr):                                                                                                                              
     try:                                                                                                                                                                       
         result = getattr(obj, attr)                                                                                                                                            
         if hasattr(result, '__call__'):                                                                                                                                        
             result()                                                                                                                                                           
     except Exception as e:                                                                                                                                                     
         if isinstance(e, exception):                                                                                                                                           
            raise AssertionError('{}.{} raises {}.'.format(obj, attr, exception))
```

could be modified if you need to accept parameters.

call like

```
self._assertNotRaises(IndexError, array, 'sort')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an Exception class to `assertRaises()`, a context manager is provided. This can improve the readability of your tests:

```
# raise exception if Application created with bad data
with self.assertRaises(pySourceAidExceptions.PathIsNotAValidOne):
    application = Application("abcdef", "")
```

This allows you to test error cases in your code.

In this case, you are testing the `PathIsNotAValidOne` is raised when you pass invalid parameters to the Application constructor.

Comment: No, this will only fail if the exception _isn't_ raised within the context manager block. Can be readily tested by 'with self.assertRaises(TypeError): raise TypeError', which passes.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor Good call. As I recall, rather than testing code executes correctly, i.e. doesn't raise, I was suggesting testing error cases. I've edited answer accordingly. Hopefully I can earn a +1 to get out of the red. :)

Comment: Note, this also is Python 2.7 and later: http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

Answer (score 1):

you can try like that. 
        try:
            self.assertRaises(None,function,arg1, arg2)
        except:
            pass
if you don't put code inside try block it will through exception' AssertionError: None not raised " and test case will be failed. Test case will be pass if put inside try block which is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

My solution - derived from accepted solution:
**Cache** error on function. **If** there is no error, Assertion error will raise. In that case -> test Passed! **Else**, write error message.

Code:

```
    try:
        with self.assertRaises((PathIsNotAValidOne, AnotherError)) as err:
            AlwaysSuppliesAnInvalidPath()
        error = str(err.exception)
    except AssertionError:
        self.assertTrue(True)
    else:
        self.fail(error)
```

And:

```
    try:
        with self.assertRaises((PathIsNotAValidOne, AnotherError)) as err:
            AlwaysSuppliesAValidPath()
        error = str(err.exception)
    except AssertionError:
        self.assertTrue(True)
    else:
        self.fail(error)
```

Little twisted logic, but works as a charm!

Answer (score -2):

One straight forward way to ensure the object is initialized without any error is to test the object's type instance.

Here is an example :

```
p = SomeClass(param1=_param1_value)
self.assertTrue(isinstance(p, SomeClass))
```