# Pass a Python unittest if an exception isn't raised

Tags: python, unit-testing

In the Python `unittest` framework, is there a way to pass a unit test if an exception wasn't raised, and fail with an AssertRaise otherwise?

Comment: I've only found the need to do this when testing legacy code and putting up a bunch of sanity tests. These are tests without any Asserts (basically verifying that the code block executes without blowing up). Any unexpected exceptions fail the test anyway - not sure if the Python frameworks works similarly to the xUnit family.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319825/python-unittest-opposite-of-assertraises

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python unittest - opposite of assertRaises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319825/python-unittest-opposite-of-assertraises)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you *could* do something like this:

```
def test_does_not_raise_on_valid_input(self):
    raised = False
    try:
        do_something(42)
    except:
        raised = True
    self.assertFalse(raised, 'Exception raised')
```

...assuming that you have a corresponding test that the correct `Exception` gets raised on invalid input, of course:

```
def test_does_raise_on_invalid_input(self):
    self.assertRaises(OutOfCheese, do_something, 43)
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, you need to consider what it is that you are *actually* testing. It's likely that a test like...

```
def test_what_is_42(self):
    self.assertEquals(do_something(42), 'Meaning of life')
```

...is better because it tests the desired behaviour of the system and will fail if an exception *is* raised.

Comment: IMHO something like this should be part of the unittest.TestCase class, it's an awkward thing to want, but I can't be the only person who wants it.

Comment: @Levi Campbell: I agree, an `assertDoesNotRaise()` method would be neater. N.B: I have edited my answer since you accepted.

Comment: Why bother to first catch an exception and then raise a different one?  Just call `do_something()`, and if an exception gets raised, the test automatically fails.  This is also the reason why `assertDoesNotRaise()` does not exist.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: You are correct and I have updated my answer accordingly. I initially answered the question as posed without giving due consideration as to the nature of the underlying problem.

Comment: No @SvenMarnach is not correct: There is a difference between raising an error and failing a test. If do_something() raises an error in your last version, then the test will exit with an error instead of registering a test failure, which is what you actually want.

Comment: @Alex While test frameworks usually distinguish between tests that raise exceptions and tests that fail assertions in the output, both of these results are considered test failures. And if test code raises an exception when it actually shouldn't, then what's wrong marking the test as an error? To me adding try/except blocks around the code looks like pointless busywork, and I can't see the value it adds.

Answer (score 29):

Many of the comments on this page treat errors and failures as equivalent, which they are not. The right solution in my opinion is to explicitly fail the test if the exception is raised. E.g.:

```
def test_does_not_error(self):
    try:
        code_under_test()
    except ThatException:
        self.fail("code_under_test raised ThatException")
```

Comment: Agree -- while the console output for errors and failures parses comparably by a human read, most automated unit testing tools treat the two quite differently, right?

Comment: It's the default assumption that code does not error out. Tests should test for desired behaviour. I don't see what value the try/except block adds. In fact, it _decreases_ the usefulness of the test, since the output won't include the traceback, which it would if you just let the code fail.

Comment: One value the try/except block adds is that it gives the OP what they were asking for.  

I understand it's a matter of preference; this style is my preference over unhandled exceptions.

By catching a specific exception that indicates a known problem, the failure can be understood faster than if one has to scan screenfuls of traceback output. 

If this were a real test and not an example, and the traceback or other details of the exception were important, they could be reported in the `self.fail` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Simply call your functionality, e.g. `do_something()`. If an unhandled exception gets raised, the test automatically fails! There is really no reason to do anything else. This is also the reason why `assertDoesNotRaise()` does not exist.

---

Credit: comment by Sven

Comment: That is not true, As if the method raises an error, then the test cases will be marked as an `error` not a `failure`

Comment: @IslamTaha What difference does it make? Either way it has to be fixed.

Comment: @Acumenus the point isn't to just fix the test, you could in principle fix the test by cheating it. The point is that the purpose of the test is to exactly have you understand what is happening in the code and distinguishing between exceptions, sheer code bugs and failures is fundamental.

Comment: If you cheat with your test, you have bigger problems. For example, if I were to put one foot on the floor when I am checking my weight, then it's not the weighing scale that is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question while looking for an answer to this obvious problem. Whilst the suggested solutions with try/except are fine, I found that I ended up with uncovered lines of code in coverage and that doesn't sit well with me. So I have come up with another solution, whilst not perfect, works for functions that only throw exceptions.

```
def check_raises(obj):
    if obj.condition is True:
        raise Exception('Condition is true')
```

In order to successfully test this function, I have resorted to using `assertIsNone`. The below code covers both cases.

```
import unittest


class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        self.condition = None


class TestCheckRaises(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_check_raises_exception(self):
        obj = Object()
        obj.condition = True
        self.assertRaises(Exception, check_raises, obj)

    def test_check_raises_no_exception(self):
        obj = Object()
        obj.condition = False
        self.assertIsNone(check_raises(obj))
```

I am with the original poster that a `assertNotRaises` would be nice, but failing that, `assertIsNone` is perfectly acceptable for functions that do not return a value.