# Test that fails if exception is rised?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

How to write a unit test that is considered failed if an exception is risen?

I've found the `assertRaises` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) but it seems to be doing the exact opposite.

**Example from Django**

If something is wrong with the database the `entry.save()` will rises an exception.

```
class TestModel(TestCase):
    def test_model_creation(self):
        try:
            entry = MyModel(name='Bob')
            entry.save()
        except Exception:
            self.assertEqual(0, 1)
```

The `self.assertEqual(0, 1)` is just a bad hack for the test to fail if there is an exception. What would be the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to try and except. If a test raises an error then it fails anyway.

Otherwise, see [this post about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319825/python-unittest-opposite-of-assertraises).