# Python unit testing, error happened and exception matched, but my program returns an `AssertionError`

Tags: python, unit-testing, rethinkdb

Here is my Python code.

```
try: ct("table_that_does_not_exist", "database_that_does_not_exists")
except r.errors.ReqlOpFailedError as e: self.fail()
```

`ct` is a function to check if a table is exist in a database. `ct` returns `True` if a table exists in the database and `False` for otherwise.

`try: ct("table_that_does_not_exist", "database_that_does_not_exists")` is trying to check a non-existent table in a non-existent database. This should returns an error of this.

```
rethinkdb.errors.ReqlOpFailedError: Database `database_that_does_not_exists` does not exist in:
r.db('database_that_does_not_exists').table_list().contains('table_that_does_not_exist')
```

However, the error is somewhat not capture in `except r.errors.ReqlOpFailedError as e: self.fail()` and returns an `AssertionError`.

I expect this to pass the test, since `ct("table_that_does_not_exist", "database_that_does_not_exists")` will return `r.errors.ReqlOpFailedError`. But I got this instead.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_check_table (__main__.test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 61, in test_check_table
    try: ct("table_that_does_not_exist", "database_that_does_not_exists")
rethinkdb.errors.ReqlOpFailedError: Database `database_that_does_not_exists` does not exist in:
r.db('database_that_does_not_exists').table_list().contains('table_that_does_not_exist')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                   

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 62, in test_check_table
    except r.errors.ReqlOpFailedError as e: self.fail()
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.050s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

The error is match but not proceed through `except`.

What is wrong with my test?

Comment: is this pytest?

Comment: No, it is the native `unittest` in Python 3.5.

Comment: What do you expect `self.fail()` to do?

Comment: Hey there! I was following this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319825/python-unittest-opposite-of-assertraises. I am still learning unit testing in general. What I want is the is to pass the test if certain exception happens. In this case I want to pass the test if `r.errors.ReqlOpFailedError` happens.

Comment: Is there a reason I got downvoted :/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your general approach to this is incorrect.
Your exception checking code should look like this:

```
with self.assertRaises(r.errors.ReqlOpFailedError):
    ct("table_that_does_not_exist", "database_that_does_not_exists")
```

Comment: Hey! This is solve my problem. But how can I have the something like "If an error is __NOT__ happening, pass the test."?

Comment: just use the `ct("table_that_does_exist", "database_that_does_exists")` snippet without `with self.asserRaises(...)`? :)

Comment: So no assertion necessary? I thought the point of unit testing in Python is that you need to refer back to those assert functions in `unittest.TestCase`. If I just use `ct("table_that_does_exist", "database_that_does_exists")` I can just do this in any class I want and not necessarily to be in a class that inherits from `unittest.TestCase` right?

Comment: if you are using `unittest` framework, I believe unittest.TestCase is necessary. But in `pytest` it's not. Regarding your question: you should find a way to "assert" that your table or database is actually exist. Something like `self.assertTrue(table_exists)`, but how do you populate this `table_exists` variable is an open question.

Comment: Hey there, I found that `try: c()\except r.errors.ReqlDriverError as e: self.fail()` is good way to check if a function went  through. If exception happens then it automatically failed the test.