# Using Django tests on model validation, how to test that a value does not raise a validation error

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

For testing completeness, I want to test that values < 0 and > 100 raise a `ValidationError` and that values > 0 and < 100 do not raise a `ValidationError` for my model field. I know that I can check if a validation error will be raised like so:
`

```
def test_validate_fee_range(self):     
    test = Foo.objects.get(name="T1")
    test.full_clean()
    test.fee = 105

    # raise Validation error for value less than 0 and greater than 100
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, test.full_clean)`
```

But how do I check that I `ValidationError` will no be raised given valid input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python unittest - opposite of assertRaises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319825/python-unittest-opposite-of-assertraises)

Comment: Yes that answers it! Thank you! Such an obvious solution.

Answer (score -1):

As per this answer: [Python unittest - opposite of assertRaises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319825/python-unittest-opposite-of-assertraises)

```
try:
    test.self_clean()
except Exception:
    self.fail("Value should not fail")
```