# How to test a function without return value in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I have a function, that adds a new record to DB and I need to test it:

```
def add_report_to_db(latitude, longitude, color: str, comment: str):
    """Add a new report to the DB."""
    try:
        report = Report(
            latitude=float(latitude),
            longitude=float(longitude),
            color=color,
            comment=comment,
            ip=request.remote_addr,
        )
        db.session.add(report)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Success!", category="success")

    except Exception as e:
        flash("Error." + str(e), category="error")
```

I do test it with this code below:

```
class BasicsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """General test cases."""

    def setUp(self):
        """Execute before unit test. Create an app and in memory DB."""
        self.app = create_app("testing")
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all()
        self.current_map = folium.Map(location=(50.45, 30.52))
        self.client = self.app.test_client(use_cookies=True)

        report = Report(
            latitude=50.45,
            longitude=30.52,
            color="red",
            comment="comment",
            ip="127.0.0.1",
        )
        db.session.add(report)
        db.session.commit()

    def tearDown(self):
        """Execute after unit test. Drop DB, session, app."""
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_add_report_to_db(self):
        """Test add a new report to the DB."""
        with current_app.test_request_context():
            result = add_report_to_db(
                latitude=50.45,
                longitude="testing",  # a purposeful error is here
                color="red",
                comment="comment",
            )
            self.assertIsNone(result)  # test passed even with exception
            self.assertRaises(not Exception, result)  # I need someting like this
```

The problem is that even if exeption occurs, the function returns None and test passes.
How do I can check that there were no any exceptions?

Comment: If it does not fail, there will be a record in the database?  Or if your are a mockist, `flash` will have been called with the success arguments.

Comment: @snakecharmerb , yes there will be a record in the database in case of successfull transaction.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4319870/5465488).

Comment: @VitaliiMytenko maybe assert that the record was created? If the func raises, that's implicitly asserted because the test will fail.